# SQL query is running for very long time

Tags: sql, join, query-optimization, sap-ase

Help me optimize the below sql,running for many many hours
Database : sybase

```
select
    too.toID,too.toName,frm.fromID,frm.fromName<br>
from
    entityClientTempTable frm, entityClientTempTable too
where
    frm.fromServerId = too.toServerId 
and
    frm.fromID < too.toID 
and 
    lower(substring(frm.fromName, 0, CHARINDEX(''------'',frm.fromName))) like lower(too.toName))
```

Number of records in entityClientTempTable : half a million approx
There are no indexes on entityClientTempTable  table
entityClientTempTable is a temporary table.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the intended result of your query? What is the end goal?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
select too.toID,too.toName,frm.fromID,frm.fromName
from entityClientTempTable frm
inner join entityClientTempTable too on frm.fromServerId = too.toServerId 
       and frm.fromID < too.toID
where lower(substring(frm.fromName, 0, CHARINDEX(''------'',frm.fromName))) like lower(too.toName))
```